# How to skip a request if it shows an error message on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a script that grabs the info from the website using selenium.

However, if it doesn't find the info and shows an error message, it skips that request and continues to the next one.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

list1 = [6019306,6049500,6051161,6022230,5776662,6151430]

for x in range(0, list1.count()):
    while True:
        try: 
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
            options.add_argument("start-maximized")
            driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
            url = 'https://www.axie.tech/axie-pricing/'+str(list1[x])
            driver.get(url)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)


            test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/span').text
            test = float(test[1:])
            print(test)


            driver.close()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            'This Value doesnt exist'
            driver.close()
```

Comment: You don't  need a `while` loop here. What is happening with the current code if the url is not found?

Comment: the url will always be found. But sometimes, the info is not available on the website. When it is not available, it shows an error message. When it shows the error message, it should skip to following urls

Comment: What kind of error / exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear what exactly you are trying to do through the line `test = float(test[1:])`.

However to extract the desired text from the list of websites you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()     
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  list1 = [6019306, 6049500, 6051161, 6022230, 5776662, 6151430]
  for x in range(0, len(list1)):
      try:
          url = 'https://www.axie.tech/axie-pricing/'+str(list1[x])
          driver.get(url)
          print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Reasonable']//following::div[1]//span[contains(@class, 'MuiTypography-root')]"))).text)
      except TimeoutException:
          continue
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Ξ0.01
  Ξ0.012
  Ξ0.0162
  Ξ0.026
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  ```

Comment: it shows an error saying s in not defined. What have you input there? because without it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Tiago Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options,executable_path='C:/Users/tiago/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
list1 = [6019306, 6049500, 6051161, 6022230, 5776662, 6151430]
for x in range(0, len(list1)):
    try:
        url = 'https://www.axie.tech/axie-pricing/'+str(list1[x])
        driver.get(url)
        print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Reasonable']//following::div[1]//span[contains(@class, 'MuiTypography-root')]"))).text)
    except TimeoutException:
        continue
driver.quit()

Comment: @Tiago Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined

Comment: @Tiago Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.